# Schedule VisualVM to take a snapshot at certain intervals

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm

Is there a way to take a Snapshot of CPU and Heap usage over time.

Say every hour for 2 days?

Comment: +1.  Note that there are tools like jstat, jmap, jps which will allow you to scripts that can run at regular intervals. http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/monitoring-java-garbage-collection-using-jstat.php

Comment: did you find any solution?